# opencart theme not changing

Tags: themes, opencart

I installed opencart 1.5.6 on my localhost, and it's not possible for me to change the theme. The admin panel says the new theme is active, but the default theme always appears.

I made the same installation on a remote server, and everything is working well there.

I have no idea what's wrong on my localhost. I'm on a new installation on Ubuntu 12.4 with a default configuration for LAMP. I tried to compare the two phpinfo but there are so many things that are different that gives me no clue.

---

It was just a problem of rights on the theme folder. Very stupid ...

Comment: Simple question - within the new theme - are there the required modified files and different CSS styles? Didn't You just copy and rename the default theme so the new theme contains all the same styles and templates as the default one?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would check your database to see if the change is registered. Use phpMyAdmin (or whatever included with your LAMP stack) and look at the "oc_setting" (prefix may differ) and see if the config_template is set to the template you've chosen via the admin. This will help identify if the issue is database related.

Comment: So if the database shows the correct theme, what would the next step be?

Comment: sorry for the late response, is there anything unique about your installation? Did you upgrade, change databases, reinstall, etc? or is this a fresh install also what is the theme you're trying to install?

Comment: I was able to fix it by adjusting the permissions of the theme directory. After that it worked much better.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution, the ACTUAL solution. (For me anyway)

1. Extract the theme.
2. Login to your OpenCart website using FTP. Please read our article if
   you need help using FTP.
3. Upload the catalog and images folders to the root of your OpenCart installation.
4. Once the upload is finished, log into your OpenCart Dashboard and go
   to System > Settings
5. Choose your website from the list, check the box next to it, and select “Edit”
6. In the store tab you will now see your new theme option available under 'Template'

Click Save.

It has now been updated.

Many, many tutorials online at the moment incorrectly instruct people to upload their theme directly into the **catalog > view > theme** location as though it were a WordPress theme or similar. You actually need to put the appropriate resources where they need to be.